# Can I write a Python Abstract class via the c api?

Tags: python, c

I'm working with some c code, which I'd like to wrap into a python abstract class via the c api.

The source I'm working with is here: https://github.com/samba-team/samba/tree/master/libgpo/gpext (part of the samba project)

I have 2 structures, a gp_extension struct and a gp_extension_methods struct. The gp_extension struct contains a reference to a gp_extension_methods struct.

```
struct gp_extension {
    struct GUID *guid;
    const char *name;
    struct gp_extension_methods *methods;
    struct gp_extension *prev, *next;
};

struct gp_extension_methods {

    NTSTATUS (*initialize)(TALLOC_CTX *mem_ctx);

    NTSTATUS (*process_group_policy)(TALLOC_CTX *mem_ctx,
                     uint32_t flags,
                     struct registry_key *root_key,
                     const struct security_token *token,
                     const struct GROUP_POLICY_OBJECT *deleted_gpo_list,
                     const struct GROUP_POLICY_OBJECT *changed_gpo_list);

    NTSTATUS (*get_reg_config)(TALLOC_CTX *mem_ctx,
                   struct gp_extension_reg_info **info);

    NTSTATUS (*shutdown)(void);
};
```

I'd like to combine these via the c api and create a gp_extension abstract base class with the gp_extension_methods as abstract methods that the derivative classes would have to implement.

My question is, does anyone know if this is possible via the python c api? If it is, does anyone know where I might find an example (I have searched and haven't found anything)?

Comment: Python doesn't really have abstract classes. See the `abc` module for how they are faked.

Comment: @chepner I'm aware of the abc module. I wonder, can decorators be applied to functions via the c-api?

Comment: I assume so, since it's just function application.